# Static factory method for a Queue

Tags: java, collections, queue

Is there a static factory method for creating a queue in Java?

I found several methods for creating Lists. For example:

```java
Arrays.asList(T... a);
```

or

```java
List.of(E... elements)
```

But can't find a convenient way to do the same for queues (or dequeues). The only solution I found is:

```java
new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(elements))
```

Comment: That seems like a fine solution.

Comment: there are no direct static methods?

Comment: No there are no available static methods in the jdk

Comment: In queue, you cannot do a random access for the elements. So you cannot have a static utility for initialization. Well you can always use a stream() to do that elegantly

Comment: @Shantanu What has random access got to do with the existence of a static factory method?

Comment: When you need a queue or deque, you should first consider `ArrayDeque` rather than `LinkedList`. But besides that, you already named a working approach. Alternatively, you can always use `Collections.addAll(collection, elements);`

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. But I don't understand why ```ArrayDequeue``` is the preferred option?

Comment: That has been discussed in [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488). The array based collections are more efficient in most use cases. There’s already a difference between `new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(elements))` and `new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(elements))`. [This tweet](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248) from the author of `LinkedList` is also illustrative.